# How to cast nativeQuery list to jpa query list?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two query list:

```
List<A> list1;
Query query = em.createQuery(sql);
list1=query.getResultList();
return list1;
```

and another list is:

```
List<A> list2;
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
list2=query.getResultList();
return list2;
```

when I tried to initialize

```
list1=list2
```

which I want to do for my requirement. But I got following exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to A
```

Please help me about this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if A is entity, then this should works:

```
TypedQuery<A> query = em.createQuery(sql,A.class);
list1=query.getResultList();
```

Comment: should be em.createNativeQuery(sql, class)

Comment: @James http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html it will work for both native sql and jpql queries